# Почему не работает write()

Tags: python-3.x

https://pastebin.com/1yAmveJ3
(в начале не важно главное последний else)

```
#Модули
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import random
#Код
init()
kana = list('アイウエオカキクケコサシスセソタチッテトナニヌネノハヒフヘホマミムメモヤユヨラリルレロワヲン')
test_kana = ['a','i','u','e','o','ka','ki','ku','ke','ko','sa','si','su','se','so','ta','ti','tsu','te','to','na','ni','nu','ne','no',
'ha','hi','fu','he','ho','ma','mi','mu','me','mo','ya','yu','yo','ra','ri','ru','re','ro','wa','wo','n']
num_symbols = 46
num_random = num_symbols - 1
isklucheniya = []
resultats={}
while len(isklucheniya)!=num_symbols:
    num=random.randint(0,num_random)
    while num in isklucheniya:
        num=random.randint(0,num_random)
        if num in isklucheniya:
                continue
        else:
            print(Fore.MAGENTA + Back.BLACK + kana[num]+' def')
            ja=input(Fore.RED)
            if ja == test_kana[num]:
                print(Back.GREEN+'Правильно')
                rez =  1
                isklucheniya.append(num)
                resultats.update({kana[num]:1})
            else:
                print(Back.RED+'Неправильно')
                rez = -1
                isklucheniya.append(num)
                resultats.update({kana[num]:1})
        break
    else:
        print(Fore.MAGENTA+ Back.BLACK + kana[num])
        ja=input(Fore.RED)
        if ja == test_kana[num]:
            print(Back.GREEN+'Правильно')
            resultats.update({kana[num]:1})
            isklucheniya.append(num)
        else:
            print(Back.RED+'Неправильно')
            resultats.update({kana[num]:-1})
            isklucheniya.append(num)
else:
    f=open('sas.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
    print(Back.YELLOW)
    print(Fore.RED)
    for i in resultats: 
        otvets = i +':'+str(resultats[i])
        print(otvets)
        f.write(otvets)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Код нужно в самом вопросе приводить

Comment: Исправил но ссылку на всякий оставил

Comment: а resultats то не пустой?

Comment: да вроде нет, и otvets выводится, но именно в файл не пишеться

Comment: А если указать полный путь то файл создается и заполняется?

Comment: Да работает и заполняется Пасиба

Comment: Ага, как я и думал... а как вы запускали скрипт?

Comment: Консоль python name.py

Comment: А в какой папке открыт был терминал (консоль)? Та папка считается рабочей директорией и если не указывать абсолютный путь, то файл появится относительно рабочей директории. Так что, в той папке ваш файл

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, этого я не знал, решил я это так ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

Comment: Вы молодец что разобрались :) решение через ROOT_DIR здравое. Оформите, пожалуйста, ответ с вашим решением :)

Answer (score 0):

gil9red Спасибо большое

## за то время пока разбирались я добавил несколько строк

```
#Модули
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import random
import os
import pickle
#Код
init()
num_symbols = 0
isklucheniya = []
resultats={}
hor = 0
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path_to_kana = ROOT_DIR+ '\\kana.txt'
path_to_otvetkana = ROOT_DIR+ '\\kana_otvet.txt'
try:
    with open(path_to_kana, 'rb') as f:
        kana=pickle.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(Back.RED+'Не загруженны файлы каны')
    exit()
try:    
    with open(path_to_otvetkana, 'rb') as f:
        test_kana=pickle.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(Back.RED+'Не загруженны файлы ответов на кану')
    exit()

for i in kana:
    num_symbols += 1
num_random = num_symbols - 1
print(Fore.CYAN+'Всё загруженно')











#Основной код

while len(isklucheniya)!=num_symbols:
    num=random.randint(0,num_random)
    while num in isklucheniya:
        num=random.randint(0,num_random)
        if num in isklucheniya:
                continue
        else:
            print(Fore.MAGENTA + Back.BLACK + kana[num])
            ja=input(Fore.RED)
            if ja == test_kana[num]:
                print(Back.GREEN+'Правильно')
                rez =  1
                isklucheniya.append(num)
                resultats.update({kana[num]:1})
            else:
                print(Back.RED+'Неправильно')
                rez = -1
                isklucheniya.append(num)
                resultats.update({kana[num]:-1})
        break
    else:
        print(Fore.MAGENTA+ Back.BLACK + kana[num])
        ja=input(Fore.RED)
        if ja == test_kana[num]:
            print(Back.GREEN+'Правильно')
            resultats.update({kana[num]:1})
            isklucheniya.append(num)
        else:
            print(Back.RED+'Неправильно')
            resultats.update({kana[num]:-1})
            isklucheniya.append(num)
else:
    path = ROOT_DIR+ '\\sas.txt'
    print(Back.YELLOW)
    print(Fore.RED)
    f=open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    f.close()
    for i in resultats: 
        if resultats[i] == 1:
            hor +=1
        otvets = i +':'+str(resultats[i])+';'
        print(otvets)
        with open(path, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(otvets+'\n')
procent = (100 * hor) / num_symbols
print(Fore.CYAN+Back.BLACK+str(round(procent)) + '%')
print('Правильных :'+str(hor) + ' Всего :'+ str(num_symbols))
with open(path, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(str(round(procent))+'%\n')
            f.write('Правильных :'+str(hor) + ' Всего :'+ str(num_symbols))
```